# Switch tabs using button to go to another tab by entering the tab number?

Tags: java, android, search, tabs

I have total of more than 1000 tabs/pages to view. I want to be able to view any tab/page by entering a number to EditText and when clicking on the Button it should jump to the specified tab. For example if I am on page 1 and if I enter "600" and hit search(button), I should be able to view that specific page and making sure the page next to 600 should be 601, 601....and before 600 should be 599, 598....

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0:

        case 1: 
            Ang100s.Ang1 ang1 = new Ang100s.Ang1();
            return ang1;

        case 2: 
            Ang100s.Ang2 ang2 = new Ang100s.Ang2();
            return ang2;
        case 3: 
            Ang100s.Ang3 ang4 = new Ang100s.Ang3();
            return ang4;
        }
        Help help = new Help();
        return help;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1430;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        for(int i = 1;i < 1430; i++){
            if(position == i){
                return "Ang " + position;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class Help extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        final Button search = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clicktosearch);
        final EditText number = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(number.getText().toString().equals("1")){

                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ViewPager you can use `setCurrentItem(int)` and pass it the index of the item you want shown. Also, your FragmentPagerAdapter needs to be able to produce an item for any index from zero to `getCount()` -- currently it does not.

Comment: I tried doing that in Help class underneath in the OnClick(View v) method by instantiating
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
main.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

Comment: That won't work. You should only have one MainActivity and you need to call it's ViewPager. Creating another MainActivity instance will not do anything of value (and most likely you will run into errors). Only the Android OS should be instantiating your activities.